# Google maps API with query string

Tags: api, google-maps

Is there a way to get a google map, either static (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap)  or dynamic, to display results from a normal search query ?

For example:
Say I want to find and display on a static map, all Wendy's Locations near zip code 84020

Can something list this be done ?

Ex:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?q=wendys,84020&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false

Answer (score 1):

enter link description herehere you go

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=wendys,84020&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false

**Updated answer based on requirement clarification**:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=wendys,84020&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false

you have to change `q=` to `center=`, be careful as the parameters are case sensitive. They won't work otherwise. The parameters [listed here](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters) should work.

**Updated again:**

Check out the StaticMap API parameters http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simplewizard/makestaticmap.html

.. and the Wizard

http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simplewizard/makestaticmap.html

P.S. search may not be possible but I imagine you could simulate a search by placing lat-long markers based on the results given here:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/geo?q=wendys,84020&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true

Comment: That still does not work.  ie, it is not doing a SEARCH for all WENDYS ( fast food ), and showing them on the map.  Perhaps it's not possible with google maps API ?

Comment: I gave you a site with a list of google map parameters to roll your own query but if you still need help, let me know and I'll give you an extra hand with this.

Comment: I went ahead and added more info :7, you can get a simulated search.